# where does odoo parse xml files to store them in the database?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, view, odoo

I want to add a button to every **form** view in odoo 10 ,I can add a model that inherit ir.ui.view and declare a function inorder to handle the button click , but the button its self How can I add it , where does odoo parse xml files to store them in the database ? ,I want to get there inorder to **inject** the button in the 
form tag --> the header tag? Programmaticly ?

Comment: Add a bad definition XML tag such as from instead of form, so your force the error. This will show you the line code that could not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place a new button near `Edit/Create` button by inheriting `FormView.buttons` template.

You can find the file here **web/static/src/xml/base.xml**

```xml
 <t t-name="FormView.buttons">
<div class="o_form_buttons_view">
    <button t-if="widget.is_action_enabled('edit')" type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary btn-sm o_form_button_edit" accesskey="a">
        Edit
    </button>
    <button t-if="widget.is_action_enabled('create')" type="button"
            class="btn btn-default btn-sm o_form_button_create" accesskey="c">
        Create
    </button>
</div>
<div class="o_form_buttons_edit">
    <button type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary btn-sm o_form_button_save" accesskey="s">
        Save
    </button>
    <button type="button"
            class="btn btn-default btn-sm o_form_button_cancel" accesskey="j">
        Discard
    </button>
</div>
</t>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: yes its the correct answer , but i already put it in the developer mode list in the same file ,and it worked.
so i will mark it as ansuer

Comment: the list item js handler will be at : *addons\web\static\src\js\widgets\debug_manager.js*